# How to send image value from form to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on one project in which there is one form filled by user and that value displayed in another page. All data I get in another page but image can't display on that page only image name is displayed. I want to display image so how can I do this?

page1

`<form action="save.php" class="contact-form" method="post" name="inputname">`  
`<table>`  
`<tr>`  
`<td class="label">Name:</td>`  
`<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="pname" /></td>`  
`</tr>`  
`<tr>`  
`<td class="label">City:</td>`  
`<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="pcity" /></td>`  
`</tr>`  
`<tr>`  
`<td class="label">Country:</td>`  
`<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="pcountry" /></td>`  
`</tr>`  
`<tr>`  
`<td class="label">Email:</td>`  
`<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="pemail" /></td>`  
`</tr>`  
`<tr>`  
`<td class="label">Upload Your Photo:</td>`  
`<td><input type="file" accept="image/jpg,image/gif" class="input-text" name="pphoto"/></td>`  
`</tr>`

page 2 save.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("my_db");
$p_name=$_POST['pname'];              
$p_city=$_POST['pcity'];
$p_country=$_POST['pcountry'];
$p_email=$_POST['pemail'];
$p_photo=$_POST['pphoto'];


<table>  
<ul>  
<tr>  
<td><li class="image"><img src="<? echo $p_photo; ?>" /></li></td>  
<li class="text">  
<td class="label">  
Name: <? echo $p_name; ?></br>    
City: <? echo $p_city; ?></br>  
Country: <? echo $p_country; ?></br>  
E-Mail: <? echo $p_email; ?></br>  
</td>  
</li>  
</tr>  
</ul>
</table>
```

Comment: Use Get or Post for this....

Comment: It would be nice to see how the main form is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload image as file then you should work with $_FILES array. And you should save uploaded image first.

Comment: What if the image from a URL? We can not really give a concrete answer until we know how the image is being handled on the main page.

Comment: If image from URL then all should work and TS was not posted this question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@$file = fopen($_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'], "r");
@$image = addslashes(fread($file, filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
```

Use your file name instead of 'file'.